# java 7 GC log format

Tags: garbage-collection

We use java 7 with following flags:
-verbose:gc
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDetails

I am looking for a full list of possible messages 
(to auto parse them).

Weird but I didn't find any complete documentation.

thanx,
Pavel.

Comment: there is an open source viewer, you may try looking into its code if you need to parse the logs yourself http://www.tagtraum.com/gcviewer.html

Comment: thanx, I"ll check that. I've actually used a different viewer for same purpose before, but apparently missed few messages. This is why i'm looking for a complete documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a official documentation for the formats. The information is spread over blogs and websites. The log format also depends on what GC you use.

I've list here a few blogs / articles:
[General](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/01/useful-jvm-flags-part-8-gc-logging/)
[Understanding the G1 GC Logs](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/understanding_g1_gc_logs)
[Understanding CMS GC Logs](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/understanding_cms_gc_logs)

Useful tools / actual parsing code: 
There are tools which can understand the GC logs. For example [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer). It also can transform the logs into a CSV format. Or you can take a look at the actual [parsers](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer/tree/develop/src/main/java/com/tagtraum/perf/gcviewer/imp).

Comment: thanx a lot! I will try those also.